# Fazer um select em que se vai buscar o id de um select feito anteriormente

Tags: php, codeigniter

Eu estou numa página em que me está a imprimir os dados de um menu. E por baixo desses dados quero que me mostre os ingredientes desse menu, sendo que vou busca-los a uma tabela lista_ingredientes.

Controller:

```
function lista_ingre()
{
    $this->load->model('ingredientes_model');
    $data['list'] = $this->ingredientes_model->getAllDisplayable_ing();
    //var_dump($data['list']); exit;
    $data['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $this->load->view('menus_detalhes_user',$data);
}
```

Model do menu:

```
function GetDisplayableByUsername_u($id)
{
    //indica os campos
    $this->db->select('id_menu, foto, nome, descricao, preco ');

    $result = $this->db->get_where('menus',array('id_menu' => $id));

    return $result->row();
}
```

Model dos ingredientes:

```
function getAllDisplayable_ing($id)
 {
    $this->db->select('id_ingrediente, lista_ingredientes.id_menu, nome_ingrediente, quantidade');
    $this->db->from('lista_ingredientes');
    $this->db->join('menus', 'menu.id_menu = lista_ingredientes.id_menu');

    $this->db->where('menu.id_menu', $id);
    $result = $this->db->get();
     return $result->result();

 }
```

View do menu:

```
     <p class="text-muted"><?php echo $menus->nome?></p>
 <p class="text-muted"><?php echo $menus->preco?>€</p>
```

View dos ingredientes:

```
 <?php foreach ($list as $lista_igredientes): ?>
                <div class="service-box">
                    <img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <h3><?php echo $lista_igredientes->nome_ingrediente?></h3>
                    <p class="text-muted"><?php echo $lista_igredientes->quantidade?></p>
                </div>
          <?php endforeach ?>
```

Os dados do menu aparecem bem na view, mas os dados dos ingredientes não. O erro é: Undefined variable: list e Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Obrigada

Comment: Você está fazendo um menu com submenu vindo do banco de dados?

Answer (score -1):

Aparentemente a variável `$list` está nula. O motivo de não trazer os dados do banco pode ser porque o método `getAllDisplayable_ing($id)` do modelo dos ingredientes recebe o parâmetro `$id` para a cláusula `$this->db->where($id)` e quando você chama esse método no controller não passa esse valor por parâmetro. Verifica se esse valor deve ser passado, se não, é só remover a cláusula where que recebe o `$id`. :)

Answer (score -1):

Eu faria dessa forma, veja se te ajuda:

```
function getAllDisplayable_ing($id=NULL)
 {

    $consuta = $this->db->get("lista_ingredientes")->result();
    foreach($consulta as &$valor){
        $this->db->where("id_menu",$valor->id_menu);
        $valor->submenu = $this->db->get("menus")->result();
    }
    return $consulta;
}
```

Passando os dados para view:

```
$data['dados_lista'] = $this->ingredientes_model->getAllDisplayable_ing();
```

Na hora de você buscar os dados na view:

```
foreach($dados_lista as $valor){
    echo $valor->nome_ingrediente."<br>"; // ingrediente
    foreach($dados_lista->submenu as $valor_sub){
        echo $valor_sub->menu; // subitem
    }
}
```